# Escribir en pantalla los números pares del 26 al 10 (descendiendo), usando "while"

Tags: c#, while

```
if (num % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num);
            while(num >= 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num--);
            }
        }
        num--;
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Este código "funciona" pero no hace lo que se me está solicitando, he pensado y pensado y no se me ocurre como hacer para que me muestre exactamente los números pares(y no todos los números como está haciendo el programa) ¿Quién me ayuda?

Answer (score 2):

Este código te permitirá leer dos números de la consola e imprimir los números pares que se encuentran entre ellos, teniendo en cuenta que el primero es mayor que el segundo.

```
Console.WriteLine("Introduce el primer número:");
int num1=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Introduce el segundo número:");
int num2=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
while(num1 >= num2){
    if(num1%2==0){
     Console.WriteLine(num1);
    }
    num1--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres imprimir sólo los números pares, recorre sólo los pares:

```
int numero = 26;

while (numero >= 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine(numero);
    numero -= 2;
}
```

Si empiezas en 26 (par) y vas restando de dos en dos, todos los números serán pares.